# Type hinting for python 3 curses wrapper

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, curses

For [curses programming](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) in Python 3, it is useful to use the `curses.wrapper` function to encapsulate the curses program, to handle errors and setup.

```py
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    # Curses program here
    pass

curses.wrapper(main)
```

But how do you add [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to the `stdscr` object? Adding type hinting would allow IDEs to provide better intellisense to the `stdscr` object and show available methods and properties. (I'm using Visual Studio Code btw)

The following code:

```py
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    s = str(type(stdscr))
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr(0,0,s)
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

...shows that `type(stdscr)` is `<class '_curses.window'>`

However this does not work:

```py
import curses
import _curses

# This does not work:
def main(stdscr: _curses.window):
    # No intellisense provided for stdscr
    pass

curses.wrapper(main)
```

And I'm not exactly sure what else to try.

Comment: It seems that *type hinting* is intended for Python scripts, not for thin bindings over C, and that what you're seeing is about all you'll get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this problem by writing the window type curses._CursesWindows in quotes
Like this:

```py
import curses

def main(stdscr: 'curses._CursesWindow'):
    # now intellisense will provide completions :)
    pass

curses.wrapper(main)
```